# How can I optimize my algo for searching with a substring?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm, object

```
search: (query) => {
  const websites = cloneDeep(this.state.websites);
  let results = [];
  websites.forEach(object => {
    let isResult = false;
    const searchIn = ["code", "link", "offline", "online"];
    for(let prop = 0; prop < 4; prop++) {
      if(isResult) break; 
      const propVal = object[searchIn[prop]];
      if(typeof propVal === "string" && propVal !== "undefined") {
        if(propVal.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
          isResult = true;              }
      }
    }
    if(isResult) results.push(object);
  });
}
```

p.s. I have an array of objects. I need to check if there is a match at least in one out of four properties of each object. "query" = substring.

Comment: Hey Heydar, welcome to SO. Please tell us a bit more about your situation, what the code is trying to achieve. A bit of intro text before launching into the code would help us to help you.

Comment: please share the object you want to iterate

Answer (score 1):

You are over complicating things here, by using a `forEach` to loop over the objects, and then iterating all the `object` keys to check if it's one of the searched properties and if its value contains the searched `query` string.

Btw your function wasn't returning anything, because you were only trying to fill the `results` array without returning it.

**Solution:**

You can simply use **[`Array#filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** to filter the `websites` array, where you iterate over the `searchIn` properties array with **[`Array#some()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** and check for each `object` relative properties and if their values contains the searched `query` string.

This is how should be your code:

```
const searchIn = ["code", "link", "offline", "online"];

search: (query) => {
  query = query.toLowerCase()
  websites.filter(o => searchIn.some(k => o[k] && typeof o[k] === "string" && o[k].toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1));
}
```

Comment: `query=query.toLowerCase()` And make sure o[k].toLowerCase is a function: `o[k] && typeof o[k].toLowerCase === "function" && o[k].toLowerCase().indexOf(query)>-1`